# laptop speakers have feedback in windows 10 but not in ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, speakers, microphone

My system is Acer E5 551G T16Q.In it ,the microphone is placed right between the speakers on the lower side of the laptop.
When I use Windows 8.1/10 there is a loud feedback with the microphone turned on.
So naturally I cannot use the speakers with the microphone(I even tried using earphones or separate USB speakers to no avail).
Recently I dual booted to Ubuntu 14.04 and found that there was no such problem of a feedback. 
I wanted to know how this was possible and also if this was also somehow possible for windows 10, because I prefer to use windows. Thanks.

Comment: Also since I'm new here, I don't know the ethics

Comment: Your are fine ethics wise.  (I was going to comment about audio gain and feedback loops, but on rereading your question I see you also have problem using earphones, which throws a curveball)

Comment: Check your Sound Settings and Volume Controls for Input Levels, there is often a mic boost feature you can disable or just lower the input or mute the microphone